# Anorm & MySQL SHA1 password encrytion is not same with Mysql Workbench command

Tags: mysql, scala, mysql-workbench, anorm

In my Play Framework Scala project I am using MySQL as database. In my database I have a column with the name `PASSWORD`. I will store the users passwords in this column when they create a new user in my project. I use `SHA1` encryption for password field while inserting a user vales. If I run the command directly in my database from MySQL Workbench, it will store the different encrypted string in my `PASSWORD` column.

**Command run in MySql Workbench**

```
INSERT into user('PASSWORD') VALUES(SHA1('hello'));
```

this SQL Query insert `aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d` this string in `PASSWORD` field

**INSERT command from Project**

```
def insert(password: String) = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL(
        """
          insert into user(PASSWORD) 
          values (
            SHA1('{password}')
          )
        """
      ).on(       
        'password -> password       
      ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }
```

This insert operation stores the `PASSWORD` value as `f0e2d8610edefa0c02b673dcac7964b02ce3e890`

**What issue I am facing**

Update my `PASSWORD` from project store value as `aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d` for password `hello`

```
SELECT USERNAME from USER WHERE PASSWORD = SHA1('hello')
```

This query returns `null` in my project because it is considering `SHA1('hello')` as `f0e2d8610edefa0c02b673dcac7964b02ce3e890`

Comment: Using Anorm 2.3+, `SQL"INSERT INTO user (PASSWORD) VALUES ($password)"` is less verbose.

Comment: @Peanut's answer is correct in that you're using prepared statements incorrectly. But SHA-1 hashing is no longer considered secure. Consider using a library like [jbcrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt) to salt+hash passwords at the application level, instead of the database level.

Comment: @m-z I will use it in future.Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f0e2d8610edefa0c02b673dcac7964b02ce3e890` is the SHA-1 hash of `{password}`.

You need to remove the quotes (`'`) around `{password}` to make it work:

```
def insert(password: String) = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL(
        """
          insert into user(PASSWORD) 
          values (
            SHA1({password})
          )
        """
      ).on(       
        'password -> password       
      ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }
```

Otherwise the framework interprets `{password}` as a String and not as a variable and therefore calculates the hash of `{passowrd}` instead of `hello`.

Comment: Yes,you are correct.It has solved my issue.Thanks lot.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem you can mark it as "accepted", so others see it worked for you (and I get additional reputation of course ;))

Comment: Sorry,I actually up voted the answer but I did forget to accept your answer.